# How to do Pivot in SQL having three fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table called product and want to perform pivot operation and looking for following results:

[image: Input Table]

OutPut Required:

[image: OutPut]

How to do Pivot in SQL having three fields?

Comment: Please indicate what you've done so far and what specifically is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select * from
(SELECT  
    *
FROM
    Product ) t
Pivot (MAX(Value) FOR Attribute in ([FLAVOUR], [INCENPRODUCT], [MANUFACTUREDBY], [PRODUCTBRAND], [PRODUCTCATEGORY], 
                                    [PRODUCTCATEGORY1], [PRODUCTCATEGORY2A], [PRODUCTCATEGORY2B]) ) P
```

Comment: I was trying the same thing but max on Product_id :P